# Shortcode called twice

Tags: shortcode

I'm working on my product information using a shortcode who automatically can generate a table with information. But it looks like the shortcode gets called twice. I'm not a great back-end developer but I'm trying to learn some basics so I can make some basic PHP functions. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

My code looks like this:

```php
function displayTable()
{
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    $fields = get_field_objects();
    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
      echo '<td>';
      echo '<td>'. $field['label'] .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. $field['value'] .'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
}
add_shortcode('popnagel-tabel', 'displayTable')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortcodes should *never* `echo`; they should always `return` the text to be displayed. See the **User Contributed Notes** in the [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) docs.

Your code should read more like this:

```
function displayTable() {
    $string = '';
    $string .=  '<table>';
    $string .=  '<tbody>';
    $fields = get_field_objects();
    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
      $string .=  '<td>';
      $string .=  '<td>'. $field['label'] .'</td>';
      $string .=  '<td>'. $field['value'] .'</td>';
      $string .=  '</tr>';
    }
    $string .=  '</tbody>';
    $string .=  '</table>';
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('popnagel-tabel', 'displayTable');
```